# writing a pure function to update deep field in a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm building a treeview with react/redux. When collapsing/expanding a node, an action is dispatched so that "toggled" field is set to true/false.
The below array is part of my redux state.

```
 Tree:{
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "Demo",
        "toggled": true,
        "active": false,
        "children": [
            {
                "id" : 21,
                "name": "example",
                "active": false,
                "toggled": false,
                 children:[...]
             }
      }
```

The below function is not good, it only returns tree with nodes of first levels updated, not the nested ones

```
function createNodes(children,corporation,type){
    if (!Array.isArray(children))
    {
        children = children ? [children] : [];
    }
    return children.map(node => {
        createNodes(node.children,corporation,type);
       if(node.id!==corporation.id){
            return ({...node,active:false}: node);
        }
        return ({...node,toggled:corporation.toggled});

}
```

Any idea how I could do that efficiently ?

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally recommended that you keep your state as flat as possible. I would try changing your state to a flat array and then updating the `children` properties to contain lists of ids instead of the children themselves. Something like this:

**State**

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name": "Demo",
        "toggled": true,
        "active": false,
        "children": [ "21" ]
    },
    {
        "id" : 21,
        "name": "example",
        "active": false,
        "toggled": false,
        children:[...]
    }
]
```

Your reducer would then become a trivial list update:

**Reducer**

```
function updateCorporation(state, newCorp) {
    return state.map(function(corp) {
        return corp.id === newCorp.id ? newCorp : corp
    })
}
```

**Deep update**

However, if you're unable to use a flat state and need to do an update on a deep tree, here's an attempt to fix your original `createNodes` function. I believe the primary issue is that you're not using recursion to generate the return value, you're just calling the function inside of itself. Try something like this (I've dropped `type` as you're not using it):

```
function createNodes(state, corporation) {
    if (state.id === corporation.id) {
        return { ...state, toggled: corporation.toggled }
    } else if (Array.isArray(state.children)) {
        const children = state.children.map(function(child){
            return createNodes(child, corporation)
        })
        return { ...state, children }
    } else {
        return state
    }
}
```

Comment: first time I call createNodes, I pass an array which is the tree not a child, so I guess there should be another loop around createNodes

Comment: It does help to keep the inputs to a recursive function consistent. I would try to pass in the whole tree in if you can, if not a loop would definitely work (you can just copy the middle branch straight out of the function and do something like `const nextChildren = children.map(...)`).

Comment: quick question: in my inital code as you can see I've added piece of code to add  square brakets if it's not an array
children = children ? [children] : [];
 right ?
I guess that's not good I should not modify the state

Comment: Ah I missed that. So children can either be an array or a single child? Yes, having a consistent data structure to begin with is generally better than trying to force it into a single format when you need to work with it.

Comment: I've fixed that thanks.

I would like to add an other function to select tree node when clicking on an item

The function you wrote would allow me to return the child with the "select" field set to "true". However I also need to change old selected item to "false", because only one can be selected within the tree. 

If I use your function as it is, it will show the selected node, but also the previous one. I could call your function twice, once for select and a second time to unselect previous one, but it's not really efficient.
I guess there is a way to do it in the same function